# Would an array be more effective than a switch case for this scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement, case

I'm displaying star ratings based on input from an API (note: only displaying, not receiving ratings at all). The following code works exactly as I need it to, but it's a very large piece of logic for something that feels like it could be massively simplified.

I read a few other tickets here that suggest that using an array might be more effective than a switch case. But because the logic depends on each case between true within a range of numbers (like more than 2.5 but less than 3) I'm not sure an array would work at all in this case.

Bottom line is this: Can this code be massively simplified somehow?

```
$stars = 3.5;

switch ($stars) {
  case ($stars > 1 && $stars <= 1.5):
    $star2 = 'dashicons-star-half';
    $star3 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    $star4 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    $star5 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    break;
  case($stars > 1.5 && $stars <= 2):
    $star2 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star3 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    $star4 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    $star5 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    break;
  case($stars > 2 && $stars <= 2.5):
    $star2 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star3 = 'dashicons-star-half';
    $star4 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    $star5 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    break;
  case($stars > 2.5 && $stars <= 3):
    $star2 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star3 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star4 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    $star5 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    break;
  case($stars > 3 && $stars <= 3.5):
    $star2 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star3 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star4 = 'dashicons-star-half';
    $star5 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    break;
  case($stars > 3.5 && $stars <= 4):
    $star2 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star3 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star4 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star5 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
    break;
  case($stars > 4 && $stars <= 4.5):
    $star2 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star3 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star4 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star5 = 'dashicons-star-half';
    break;
  case($stars > 4.5):
    $star2 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star3 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star4 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    $star5 = 'dashicons-star-filled';
    break;
  default:
  $star2 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
  $star3 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
  $star4 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
  $star5 = 'dashicons-star-empty';
}

?>
 <div class="wporg-ratings" title="<?php echo $stars; ?> out of 5 stars" style="color:#e6b800;">
   <span class="dashicons dashicons-star-filled"></span>
   <span class="dashicons <?php echo $star2; ?>"></span>
   <span class="dashicons <?php echo $star3; ?>"></span>
   <span class="dashicons <?php echo $star4; ?>"></span>
   <span class="dashicons <?php echo $star5; ?>"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: It looks like the amount of filled stars is 1 less than the actual $star value is that correct? Mean if $stars = 3.5 then there will be 2 filled and 1 half star.

Comment: @AbraCadaver If you look down at the html, the first star is always filled. ^^

Comment: Yes, @Jon is right. In this system it's not possible to have less than 1 star reviews, so the 1st star is always filled, which is why it always starts with $star2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think an array or a switch are needed. You can use a for loop, and check the `$stars` value against your loop variable to see which icon should be used.

```
<div class="wporg-ratings" title="<?php echo $stars; ?> out of 5 stars" style="color:#e6b800;">
<?php
// for loop: one iteration for each of five possible stars
// (for loops are generally best for repeating code a specific number of times)
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    if ($stars <= $i ) {
        // empty stars are displayed when the iterator (i) is >= the star value
        echo  '<span class="dashicons dashicons-star-empty"></span>';
    } elseif ($stars <= $i + 0.5) {
        // half stars are displayed for star values between i and i+0.5 
        echo  '<span class="dashicons dashicons-star-half"></span>';
    } else {
        // whole stars are displayed when the star value is > i+0.5
        echo  '<span class="dashicons dashicons-star-filled"></span>';
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

To help understand why this works, take a theoretical value through the loop. We can use the one from your question, `3.5`.

- first iteration: 3.5 > 0, 3.5 > 0.5, so you get the else value (filled star)
- second iteration: 3.5 > 1, 3.5 > 1.5, so you get the else value (filled star)
- third iteration:  3.5 > 2, 3.5 > 2.5, so you get the else value (filled star)
- fourth iteration: 3.5 > 3, 3.5 = 3.5, so you get the elseif value (half star)
- fifth iteration: 3.5 < 4, so you get the if value (empty star)

Comment: Wow. That works perfectly. Can you elaborate just a little on WHY/HOW exactly this works. I've seen loops like this before, but I'm confused how the right amount of stars are always spit out with this loop and how this knows exactly when to trigger a half star or an empty star.

Will definitely mark this as the accepted answer with your clarifications.

Comment: @MattCromwell I edited the answer. I hope the explanation and example is helpful.

Comment: Perfect @dont-panic thanks for the additional details. Helps me understand much better.

Answer (score 1):

here is quick version:

```
$stars = 3.5;
$d = array(
    ($stars >= 1.0) ? 'dashicons-star-filled' : (($stars >= 0.5) ? 'dashicons-star-half' : 'dashicons-star-empty'),
    ($stars >= 2.0) ? 'dashicons-star-filled' : (($stars >= 1.5) ? 'dashicons-star-half' : 'dashicons-star-empty'),
    ($stars >= 3.0) ? 'dashicons-star-filled' : (($stars >= 2.5) ? 'dashicons-star-half' : 'dashicons-star-empty'),
    ($stars >= 4.0) ? 'dashicons-star-filled' : (($stars >= 3.5) ? 'dashicons-star-half' : 'dashicons-star-empty'),
    ($stars >= 5.0) ? 'dashicons-star-filled' : (($stars >= 4.5) ? 'dashicons-star-half' : 'dashicons-star-empty')
);
echo '<div class="wporg-ratings" title="' . $stars . ' out of 5 stars" style="color:#e6b800;">';
foreach ($d as $value) echo '<span class="dashicons ' . $value . '"></span>';
echo '</div>';
```

it is not the same as your original logic (when first star is always filled), but you can use it as direction

next step could be moving repeated code into function

Comment: I considered ternary operators but didn't think of them in combination with an array. That's pretty creative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to define an array of hashes. Let's say that that each element in the array contains "minimum value, and three strings," and that the array is sorted in ascending order. Your if/then logic could be replaced by a loop through that array, breaking-out as soon as it can.

**However:** *"Clarity* trumps all other concerns." If the code *works* and is reasonably maintainable, who cares if it stinks?

Your existing code could be simplified to eliminate the possibility of any value "falling through the cracks" by noticing that the first half of the if-condition can be omitted:  if you reach the second case, it must be true that the value is greater than 1.5, and so on.

Comment: Yes, I was willing to leave the code as-is since it works and is extremely readable. But I knew there had to be a more efficient way to produce the same results which would most likely also have much better performance. I think @dont-panic has a solution that teaches me quite a bit, is far better performing and much less code overall.